# SQL Server 2008 - Keyword search using table Join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, join

Ok, I created a Stored Procedure that, among other things, is searching 5 columns for a particular keyword.  To accomplish this, I have the keywords parameter being split out by a function and returned as a table.  Then I do a Left Join on that table, using a LIKE constraint.

So, I had this working beautifully, and then all of the sudden it stops working.  Now it is returning every row, instead of just the rows it needs.

The other caveat, is that if the keyword parameter is empty, it should ignore it.

Given what's below, is there A) a glaring mistake, or B) a more efficient way to approach this?

Here is what I have currently:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_getOppsPaged] 
@startRowIndex int,
@maximumRows int,
@city varchar(100) = NULL,
@state char(2) = NULL,
@zip varchar(10) = NULL,
@classification varchar(15) = NULL,
@startDateMin date = NULL,
@startDateMax date = NULL,
@endDateMin date = NULL,
@endDateMax date = NULL,
@keywords varchar(400) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
    SELECT opportunities.*,
    organizations.*,
    departments.dept_name,
    departments.dept_address,
    departments.dept_building_name,
    departments.dept_suite_num,
    departments.dept_city,
    departments.dept_state,
    departments.dept_zip,
    departments.dept_international_address,
    departments.dept_phone,
    departments.dept_website,
    departments.dept_gen_list,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY opp_id) AS RowNum
    FROM opportunities 
    JOIN departments ON opportunities.dept_id = departments.dept_id 
    JOIN organizations ON departments.org_id=organizations.org_id
    LEFT JOIN Split(',',@keywords) AS kw ON 
        (title LIKE '%'+kw.s+'%' OR
        [description] LIKE '%'+kw.s+'%' OR
        tasks LIKE '%'+kw.s+'%' OR
        requirements LIKE '%'+kw.s+'%' OR
        comments LIKE '%'+kw.s+'%')
    WHERE 
    (
        (@city IS NOT NULL AND (city LIKE '%'+@city+'%' OR dept_city LIKE '%'+@city+'%' OR org_city LIKE '%'+@city+'%'))
        OR
        (@state IS NOT NULL AND ([state] = @state OR dept_state = @state OR org_state = @state))
        OR
        (@zip IS NOT NULL AND (zip = @zip OR dept_zip = @zip OR org_zip = @zip))
        OR
        (@classification IS NOT NULL AND (classification LIKE '%'+@classification+'%'))
        OR
        ((@startDateMin IS NOT NULL AND @startDateMax IS NOT NULL) AND ([start_date] BETWEEN @startDateMin AND @startDateMax))
        OR
        ((@endDateMin IS NOT NULL AND @endDateMax IS NOT NULL) AND ([end_date] BETWEEN @endDateMin AND @endDateMax))

        OR
        (
            (@city IS NULL AND 
            @state IS NULL AND 
            @zip IS NULL AND 
            @classification IS NULL AND 
            @startDateMin IS NULL AND 
            @startDateMax IS NULL AND 
            @endDateMin IS NULL AND 
            @endDateMin IS NULL)
        )
    )
)

SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum >= @startRowIndex
AND RowNum < @startRowIndex + @maximumRows;
END
```

Comment: Do you have the previous version that worked properly?

Comment: I don't know what changed between what was working and this version.

Comment: May I suggest that you start using source code control, if you don't already.

Comment: @AaronWagner - Do you need more help for this query ?

Comment: No, I went a different, less expensive route and used dynamically generated SQL (on the SQL Server side).

Answer (score 0):

**Query** -

1. Can you show us the Previous version that was working?
2. Are you using any source control to keep track of the changes made?

### My Suggestions

Like `Predicate` with `%%` seems very expensive and slow process. Is it possible for you to user `Full Text Index` ?

Declare `local variable` for each `Input Parameter`. Assign the corresponding column name to this variable. In case of City, as three columns are being used, so declare three variables for City and assign the corresponding column names,  Like below...

```
Set @Local_city = 'city'
Set @Local_dept_city = 'dept_city'
```

finally you can use it in the `Where clause`. Doing this will exclude the below lines of code.

```
OR
 (
       (@city IS NULL AND 
       @state IS NULL AND 
       @zip IS NULL AND 
       @classification IS NULL AND 
       @startDateMin IS NULL AND 
       @startDateMax IS NULL AND 
       @endDateMin IS NULL AND 
       @endDateMin IS NULL)
```

---

> So, I had this working beautifully, and then all of the sudden it
>   stops working. Now it is returning every row, instead of just the rows
>   it needs.

Are you sure about the operators being used in the query? I mean everywhere you have `OR` operator.

> The other caveat, is that if the keyword parameter is empty, it should
>   ignore it.

Please check my above suggestion.

### Final Query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_getOppsPaged] 
@startRowIndex int,
@maximumRows int,
@city varchar(100) = NULL,
@state char(2) = NULL,
@zip varchar(10) = NULL,
@classification varchar(15) = NULL,
@startDateMin date = NULL,
@startDateMax date = NULL,
@endDateMin date = NULL,
@endDateMax date = NULL,
@keywords varchar(400) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @Local_city varchar(100)
declare @Local_dept_city varchar(100)
declare @Local_org_city varchar(100)
Declare @Local_state char(2)
Declare @Local_dept_state char(2)
Declare @Local_org_state char(2)
Declare @Local_zip varchar(10)
Declare @Local_dept_zip varchar(10)
Declare @Local_org_zip varchar(10)
Declare @Local_classification varchar(15)
Declare @Local_startDateMin date
Declare @Local_startDateMax date
Declare @Local_endDateMin date
Declare @Local_endDateMin date
Declare @Local_endDateMax date

Set @Local_city = 'city'
Set @Local_dept_city = 'dept_city'
Set @Local_org_city = 'org_city'
Set @Local_state = 'state'
Set @Local_dept_state = 'dept_state'
Set @Local_org_state = 'org_state'
Set @Local_zip = 'zip'
Set @Local_dept_zip = 'dept_zip'
Set @Local_org_zip = 'org_zip'
Set @Local_classification = 'classification'
Set @Local_startDateMax = 'startDateMax'
Set @Local_endDateMin = 'endDateMin'
Set @Local_endDateMin = 'endDateMin'
Set @Local_endDateMax = 'endDateMax'

;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
    SELECT opportunities.*,
    organizations.*,
    departments.dept_name,
    departments.dept_address,
    departments.dept_building_name,
    departments.dept_suite_num,
    departments.dept_city,
    departments.dept_state,
    departments.dept_zip,
    departments.dept_international_address,
    departments.dept_phone,
    departments.dept_website,
    departments.dept_gen_list,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY opp_id) AS RowNum
    FROM opportunities 
    JOIN departments ON opportunities.dept_id = departments.dept_id 
    JOIN organizations ON departments.org_id=organizations.org_id
    LEFT JOIN Split(',',@keywords) AS kw ON 
        (title LIKE '%'+kw.s+'%' OR
        [description] LIKE '%'+kw.s+'%' OR
        tasks LIKE '%'+kw.s+'%' OR
        requirements LIKE '%'+kw.s+'%' OR
        comments LIKE '%'+kw.s+'%')
    WHERE 
    (
        (@city IS NOT NULL AND (city LIKE '%'+@Local_city+'%' OR dept_city LIKE '%'+@Local_dept_city+'%' OR org_city LIKE '%'+@Local_org_city+'%'))
        OR
        (@state IS NOT NULL AND ([state] = @Local_state OR dept_state = @Local_dept_state OR org_state = @Local_org_state))
        OR
        (@zip IS NOT NULL AND (zip = @Local_zip OR dept_zip = @Local_dept_zip OR org_zip = @Local_org_zip))
        OR
        (@classification IS NOT NULL AND (classification LIKE '%'+@Local_classification+'%'))
        OR
        ((@startDateMin IS NOT NULL AND @Local_startDateMax IS NOT NULL) AND ([start_date] BETWEEN @Local_startDateMax AND @Local_startDateMax))
        OR
        ((@endDateMin IS NOT NULL AND @Local_endDateMax IS NOT NULL) AND ([end_date] BETWEEN @Local_endDateMin AND @Local_endDateMax))
    )
)

SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum >= @startRowIndex
AND RowNum < @startRowIndex + @maximumRows;
END
```